# Работа с бинарным файлом

Tags: c++, binary-file

Есть бинарный файл. Нужно сделать проверку на пустоту, и если `false`, то очистить его. Как реализовать? Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ofstream work;
    ifstream work_2;
    char answer;

    ofstream work("test.txt", ios::binary);
ifstream work_2;


if (work_2.read("test.txt" ,ios::binary | ios::in)!=NULL){
    cout << " Вы действительно хотите удалить старый файл и вместо него создать новый?" << endl;
    cout << " 1-Да" << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    if(answer=='1'){
        work_2.open("test.txt", ios::binary | ios::out);
        cout << " Новый файл успешно создан. Для продолжения работы с файлом перейдите в меню." << endl;
        cout << " Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу." << endl;
        getch();
        work_2.close();
    }
}

else{
    cout << " Вы отказались от создания нового файла, поэтому будете перемещены в Главное меню." << endl;
    cout << " Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу." << endl;
    getch();
}

//work_2.close();
work.close();
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то достаточно просто его создать пустым заново...

```
{
    ofstream Out("filename.ext");
}
```

По умолчанию - это именно то поведение, которое надо.

Comment: А сама проверка является правильной?